# Phone keeps dropping windows hosted network when downloading app updates

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, usb, android

I have this old TP-Link mini wireless usb adapter TL-WN723N V1

On my windows 10 home (19045 build) i created / started hosted network (via netsh) and enabled internet connection sharing.

On my android phone (Samsung s10+) i can connect to that network and everything works fine, i have internet access.

Problem: As soon as phone starts downloading app updates, network disconnects and it shows "Connected without internet". After that i just turn off wifi, replug wifi adapter and start hostednetwork again, and im keep repeating that until update is fully downloaded.

I've tried turning off power managment for usb adapter, creating a new hosted network, plugging adapter to usb 2.0, switching mac address on my phone and etc..

EDIT: Turning Metered network in my phone seems fixed that problem. Thanks [Peregrino69](https://superuser.com/users/330527/peregrino69) for suggesting that.

Comment: Do you have "Metered connection" enabled somewhere, either in Windows or in the phone?

Comment: Microsoft now pushes Wi-Fi Direct rather than Hosted Network, but I don't know if this applies to you. You might try the trial of [Connectify Hotspot](https://connectify.me/), currently heavily discounted.

Comment: Peregrino69 thanks, your suggestion fixed that problem.